# How to cherry-pick from superproject repo to subfolder repo?

Tags: git, git-subtree, git-subrepo

After [splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository) can you still use the original repo as a remote and `cherry-pick` pruned commits to the new repository.

The only option I could think of is getting the `filter-branch` the second time, pushing it as a second remote, then `cherry-pick` from the second remote to the new repository.

I don't know if this would be the reverse submodules or reverse subtrees.

Answer (score 0):

Git's *really* flexible about things like this. If your other repo's on a shared filesystem you can even

```
GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES=/path/to/other/repos/.git/objects \
git cherry-pick $itssha1
```

Comment: I get `bad object <commit hash>`